# Handling oauth2 redirect from electron (or other desktop platforms)

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, electron

This is mostly a lack of understanding of oauth2 and probably not specific to electron, however I'm trying to wrap my head around how someone would handle an oauth2 redirect url from a desktop platform, like electron?

Assuming there is no webservice setup as part of the app, how would a desktop application prompt a user for credentials against a third party oauth2 service, and then authenticate them correctly?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Electron JS runs a browser instance on your localhost. Therefore, you can handle an oauth2 redirect url by supplying a callback url of https:localhost/whatever/path/you/want. Just be sure to white list it on the oauth2 app registration page for whatever service you are using.

Example:

```
var authWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800, 
    height: 600, 
    show: false, 
    'node-integration': false,
    'web-security': false
});
// This is just an example url - follow the guide for whatever service you are using
var authUrl = 'https://SOMEAPI.com/authorize?{client_secret}....'

authWindow.loadURL(authUrl);
authWindow.show();
// 'will-navigate' is an event emitted when the window.location changes
// newUrl should contain the tokens you need
authWindow.webContents.on('will-navigate', function (event, newUrl) {
    console.log(newUrl);
    // More complex code to handle tokens goes here
});

authWindow.on('closed', function() {
    authWindow = null;
});
```

A lot of inspiration taken from this page: http://manos.im/blog/electron-oauth-with-github/

Comment: I am using Electron for Spotify's Authentication. To do so I need to pass the Redirect URI within the `authUrl`. How can I use something like `https://localhost/callback` when not using something like Node.js's "express" module to define the path?

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it was very helpful. One note - I found that the 'did-get-redirect-request' event is a little more reliable than 'will-navigate' for some APIs where they instantly redirect you if you're already authorized.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by  ' electron js runs a browser instance on your localhost' ? This is not the case when electron app is packaged for production. As you can see, this is the error I get from keycloak - take a note of the redirect_uri is no longer a valid uri, instead it is a referencing the index.html file.. WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-4) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=codingpedia, clientId=invoices-ui, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_redirect_uri, redirect_uri=file:///tmp/.mount_react-myxJe9/resources/app.asar/build/index.html

Comment: @johnwick0831 How did you solve the problem in the end?

Comment: This is just straight-up, not true, or at least poorly worded. Even in development, Electron does not host any servers on its own. The development servers are being hosted by another tool. Nice that it worked for OP, but don't be too surprised if this doesn't work in your specific case.

Answer (score 6):

Thank you for this solution. I also noticed that the navigate events from the webContents are not reliable when no clicks on the browser window triggers the redirection to the application redirect uri. For example Github login page would never trigger this event with the redirect URI if I was already logged in in the browser window. (It was probably using some session storage).

The workaround I found was to use [WebRequest](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-request) instead

```
const { session } = require('electron');

// my application redirect uri
const redirectUri = 'http://localhost/oauth/redirect'

// Prepare to filter only the callbacks for my redirectUri
const filter = {
  urls: [redirectUri + '*']
};

// intercept all the requests for that includes my redirect uri
session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeRequest(filter, function (details, callback) {
  const url = details.url;
  // process the callback url and get any param you need

  // don't forget to let the request proceed
  callback({
    cancel: false
  });
});
```

Comment: it blocks redirection and shows blank page but now how to send the user to a particular page like index.html so this whole flow makes a sense

Comment: In the callback function, you can pass a redirectURL. The API documentation is available here: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-request#webrequestonbeforerequestfilter-listener

Comment: This really helped me out. My app already handled all the oAuth work client side so the other examples were not useful. One suggestion is possibly adding this line after you set the url.

```
const query = details.url.split('?')[1];
mainWindow.loadURL('file://${__dirname}/../index.html?${query})
```