# Electron: how to open an url in the same window and after the user do some action go back to application in the same window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I have an Electron app that is displayed using `BrowserWindow`. I want to open an external URL in the same window so that the user can log in (to an external website) and after the user logs in it should display the Electron application again instead of the external website that the user used to log in.

I've been able to open the external url in the same window by using:

```
<a href="https://loginsite-example.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
  site where you have to log in
</a>
```

However, I don't know how to show the Electron application again after the user successfully logs in to the external website. Also, I would like to keep the session from the external website so that I could consume its API inside the electron application.

Comment: You should look for some topics related to electron and OAuth (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37546656/handling-oauth2-redirect-from-electron-or-other-desktop-platforms)

Comment: Just to confirm, are you wanting your Electron app to load a local (file) window, upon clicking a 'login' button or link, load a remote (URL) and then once logged in, appear to go back by loading a local (file) window (again)?

Comment: @midnight-coding exactly that

Comment: Ok, that can be done (I think). As an alternative solution, could you create a local login (file) window that posts the users login details (over https) and receives a (successful or failed) response? You mentioned that you wish to keep the session information. If your application (once logged in) can already use the API, can the API handle a login as well?

Comment: @midnight-coding nice idea maybe I will try this approach later.. thanks :)

Comment: @midnight-coding but do you know if there's another approach without "creating a custom file for login"? I mean really load an url and then load the "local files" again?

Comment: Absolutely, it can be done. I'll post an answer when I have a moment today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moving between window sources, whether it be local (file) or remote (URL) can be accomplished by just calling `window.loadFile(...)` or `window.loadURL(...)`, but only after the instance of the window has been created.

`main.js` (main thread)

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

const nodePath = require("path");

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;

function createWindow() {
    return new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });
}

function showMainWindow() {
    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); })
}

function showLoginWindow() {
    // window.loadURL('https://www.your-site.com/login')
    window.loadFile('login.html') // For testing purposes only
        .then(() => { window.show(); })
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
    showMainWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// ----- IPC -----

electronIpcMain.on('message:loginShow', (event) => {
    showLoginWindow();
})

electronIpcMain.on('message:loginSuccessful', (event, session) => {
    showMainWindow();
})
```

---

`index.html` (render thread)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Main Window</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>Main Window</div><hr>

        <button type="button" id="show-login">Login</button>
    </body>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('show-login').addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.ipcRender.send('message:loginShow');
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

---

`login.html` (render thread)

Used for testing purposes only as we do not have access to a real login page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login Window</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>Login Window</div><hr>

        <label for="username">Username: </label>
        <input type="text" id="username"><br>

        <label for="password">Password: </label>
        <input type="password" id="password"><br>

        <button type="button" id="login">Login</button>
    </body>

    <script>
        // For testing purposes only.
        document.getElementById('login').addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.ipcRender.send('message:loginSuccessful');
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

---

And finally, a `preload.js` script to communicate safely between the main thread and render thread(s).

`preload.js` (main thread)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron components.
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels.
const ipc = {
    'render': {
        // From render to main.
        'send': [
            'message:loginShow',
            'message:loginSuccessful'
        ],
        // From main to render.
        'receive': [],
        // From render to main and back again.
        'sendReceive': []
    }
};

// Exposed protected methods in the render process.
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods.
    'ipcRender', {
        // From render to main.
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render.
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again.
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.sendReceive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

A problem that will need to be overcome is once you submit your login credentials to the server, how are you going to get the session data? Your html Javascript will need to detect if and when the necessary session data is available. Once the session data is available, it is an easy process of transferring the session via IPC from the render thread to the main thread. To figure this out, one will require some additional information and understanding of your login system (a separate StackOverflow question).

As a pre-cursor, I suspect one would need to detect in the main thread when the login page has been submitted to the server via something like [`window.webContents.on('did-navigate', ...)`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#event-did-navigate). Once detected, check the next loaded page quickly to see if a session exists. If so, get it, send it to the main thread and then redirect back to the `index.html` page.

I think there should be an easier way if you can login via an API. Then the whole process can be self-contained in your Electron application. IE: Show local (file) `login.html`, submit data to server and await a "success" or "fail" response. If successful, pass the session data in the response. If unsuccessful, display an appropriate error message.

Comment: Thank you very much I appreciate a lot the time and effort you spent to help me! I figured it out how to get the session data using the following: 
`authWindow.webContents.on("did-navigate", async (event, url) => {
   const sessionId = await authWindow.webContents.session.cookies.get({name:"_session_id"});   
 });` 

Again thank you!